# jquery select remove undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using jquery how do i remove the one of the elements of the select dropdown where the value

```
<option value=" ">undefined</option>
```

i tried

```
$("#subType option[value=' ']").remove();
$("#subType option[value='']").remove();
```

None of them worked.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#subType option:contains(undefined)").remove();
```

But note that this will also remove options like:

```
<option value="foo">undefined bar</option>
```

You can read about any method in the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). It is divided into categories which makes finding easier, e.g. traversing, manipulation, etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Felix. what is he best place for me to read/refer documentation on jquery? especially the form elements.

Comment: The jQuery documentation would be the best place, but I also like quick references like this one: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#learn-the-library

Answer (score 1):

In case removing options like 'undefined blah blah' is not desired, this will remove the exact text:

```
$('#subType option').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == 'undefined';
  }).remove();
```